# Keep (click) effect when (mouseleave)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mouseevent

I am working on a custom star rating system, and also one using circles, for Angular 7.

I found this example which works fine: [Star rating example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m17rjg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

This example uses only the (click) event, but I added this to see how (mouseenter) and (mouseleave) would work:

```
(mouseenter)="countStar(star)" (mouseleave)="countStar()"
```

For my own system, I need the (mouseenter) effect, like a CSS :hover, and the (click) effect because I send some data after the user has clicked on a star.
About the (mouseleave) event, I need it to work only when the user has not yet clicked on a star.

Currently, I don't manage to disable the (mouseleave) event even after a click.
Can someone tell me how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: why do you need mouseleave event in the first place?

Comment: @epascarello To remove the added color when the user leaves the stars.

Comment: Why is it not just CSS?

Comment: @epascarello Because I want it all in one place, not the :hover effect on the star hovered + all previous in CSS (which is not easy), and the click event in TS.

Comment: You're actually complicating stuffs by trying to keep everything in a single place. For your requirement you'd need to introduce a boolean flag like `isClicked` and set it to `true` in the `(click)` event handler. Then you'd need to check in the `(mouseleave)` event handler if the flag `isClicked` is false before proceeding.

Comment: @MichaelD I tried something similar with a boolean but it didn't work. Can you show me the code you would write?

Comment: `if (this.hasValue) { return ;}`....

Comment: @epascarello This I know, but I can't write it. I call the same function for the three events. Is there a way to set the conditional directly into the mouseleave event?

Comment: Why would you set a boolean on the mouseleave? The mouseleave checks to see if a value is set....

Comment: @epascarello So how to set it in TS when I call the same function? I can't check if the function was called by mouseenter, mouseleave, or click...

Comment: Why are you calling the same function? Or you have to pass in the event and see what the event is

Comment: @epascarello About calling three different functions and checking with a if statement. That doesn't work. I tried earlier. You can check. It is like the mouseleave doesn't get that the boolean has been set on true with the click.

Comment: Show what you tried...

Comment: @MichaelD Your advice worked, I let you put your answer ;) Don't know why It didn't work when I tried it earlier.